# How to choose elements of a matrix with internally generated variables and rank them with real coefficients

Tags: matrix, machine-precision, coefficients

I have a Code (a long one), part of it is below. The following piece basically multiplies an adjacency matrix with a vector of equilibrium values. Then tries to pick non-zero elements to be used in other sections of the Code. The entire Code is in DynamicModule with a Manipulate inside since I wanted to simulate the model with different random numbers.

My question is that, although I know my matrix `a` exists with positive numbers, I cannot extract those numbers and hence the entire Code fails.

The matrix `a` is given as follows:

```
a = {{0, 0, 0, 7.55596 FE`alfa$$1563[4] FE`tao$$1563[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.55596 FE`alfa$$1563[19] FE`tao$$1563[1], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.461227 FE`alfa$$1563[14] FE`tao$$1563[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.665655 FE`alfa$$1563[17] FE`tao$$1563[4], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.14909 FE`alfa$$1563[6] FE`tao$$1563[5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.14909 FE`alfa$$1563[11] FE`tao$$1563[5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.34426 FE`alfa$$1563[11] FE`tao$$1563[6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1.66264 FE`alfa$$1563[4] FE`tao$$1563[8], .66264 FE`alfa$$1563[5] FE`tao$$1563[8], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0., 0, 0, 0, 0.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.32564 FE`alfa$$1563[8] FE`tao$$1563[10], 0, 0, 0, 4.32564 FE`alfa$$1563[12] FE`tao$$1563[10], 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.32564 FE`alfa$$1563[17] FE`tao$$1563[10], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.02967 FE`alfa$$1563[14] FE`tao$$1563[11], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 154.893 FE`alfa$$1563[7] FE`tao$$1563[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.152293 FE`alfa$$1563[6] FE`tao$$1563[14], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.152293 FE`alfa$$1563[13] FE`tao$$1563[14], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.152293 FE`alfa$$1563[18] FE`tao$$1563[14], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0., 0., 0, 0., 0., 0, 0, 0, 0., 0, 0, 0.}, {5.96944 FE`alfa$$1563[1] FE`tao$$1563[17], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.96944 FE`alfa$$1563[10] FE`tao$$1563[17], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.96944 FE`alfa$$1563[18] FE`tao$$1563[17], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.93381 FE`alfa$$1563[3] FE`tao$$1563[19], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.93381 FE`alfa$$1563[13] FE`tao$$1563[19], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0., 0, 0, 0, 0., 0., 0., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Now I try to extract all nonzero values with

```
nonzeroes = Reap[Sow[#, # > 0] & /@ Flatten[a];, True][[2]] // Flatten;
```

But for some reason, this does evaluate to the empty list `{}`.

Hope to receive some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: I also edited your question in order to boil it down to the essentials. Welcome at Mathematica.StackExchange!

Comment: Thank you very much. Excellent.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand your question correctly. But by using `SparseArray`, you can extract nonzero positions and nonzero values as follows:

```
spa = SparseArray[a];
```

Extracting the nonzero positions:

```
spa["NonzeroPositions"]


(*
{{1, 4}, {1, 19}, {3, 14}, {4, 17}, {5, 6}, {5, 11}, {6, 11}, {8, 4}, {8, 5}, {10, 8}, {10, 12}, {10, 17}, {11, 14}, {13, 7}, {14, 6}, {14, 13}, {14, 18}, {17, 1}, {17, 10}, {17, 18}, {19, 3}, {19, 13}}
*)
```

Extracting the nonzero values:

```
spa["NonzeroValues"]

(*
{7.55596 FE`alfa$$1563[4] FE`tao$$1563[1], 
 7.55596 FE`alfa$$1563[19] FE`tao$$1563[1], 
 0.461227 FE`alfa$$1563[14] FE`tao$$1563[3], 
 0.665655 FE`alfa$$1563[17] FE`tao$$1563[4], 
 3.14909 FE`alfa$$1563[6] FE`tao$$1563[5], 
 3.14909 FE`alfa$$1563[11] FE`tao$$1563[5], 
 3.34426 FE`alfa$$1563[11] FE`tao$$1563[6], 
 1.66264 FE`alfa$$1563[4] FE`tao$$1563[8], 
 1.66264 FE`alfa$$1563[5] FE`tao$$1563[8], 
 4.32564 FE`alfa$$1563[8] FE`tao$$1563[10], 
 4.32564 FE`alfa$$1563[12] FE`tao$$1563[10], 
 4.32564 FE`alfa$$1563[17] FE`tao$$1563[10], 
 1.02967 FE`alfa$$1563[14] FE`tao$$1563[11], 
 154.893 FE`alfa$$1563[7] FE`tao$$1563[13], 
 0.152293 FE`alfa$$1563[6] FE`tao$$1563[14], 
 0.152293 FE`alfa$$1563[13] FE`tao$$1563[14], 
 0.152293 FE`alfa$$1563[18] FE`tao$$1563[14], 
 5.96944 FE`alfa$$1563[1] FE`tao$$1563[17], 
 5.96944 FE`alfa$$1563[10] FE`tao$$1563[17], 
 5.96944 FE`alfa$$1563[18] FE`tao$$1563[17], 
 1.93381 FE`alfa$$1563[3] FE`tao$$1563[19], 
 1.93381 FE`alfa$$1563[13] FE`tao$$1563[19]}
 *)
```

If you insist on using `Sow` and `Reap`, then you should use `UnsameQ` as test for nonnullity as `>`, `!=` and `<` won't evaluate in gereral if they are applied to expressions that involve symbols.

```
b = Reap[If[(# =!= 0) && (# =!= 0.), Sow[#]] & /@ Flatten[a], _][[2, 1]]
```

Comment: Dear Henrik, You have already answered my question. I prepared a simple executable example to post with the answer you gave me. I am a new comer and I do not know if have any reputation to vote for your answer. I will try to give all my reputations, which only 1, I think. Furthermore, I do not know if I should post the working example with your input. I would appreciate if you let me know.

Comment: Okay, if this already settles your question: Fine. In order to accept my answer, just click the checkmark below the up- and downvote buttons. If you also click the upvote button, it will count as an upvote once you made the 15 reputation mark. The nice thing about stackexchange: Upvoting does not cost you any reputation. So you really don't have to "pay" other users: it is for free. (But everybody enjoys getting rep as sign of gratitude.)

Comment: I just noticed that   "b" is not identical to spa["NonzeroValues"] because there is an extra "0" at the end of the b sequence. How can we remove that zero?

Comment: @Tebernus Godd point. I added a test against the floating point zero `0.`.

Comment: it now works perfect. Tugrul